# How should I refactor this conditional code in ruby?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

How to refactor this function?

```
  def split_description(first_n)
    description_lines = description.split "\n"
    line_num = description_lines.length
    if line_num > first_n
      @description_first = to_html(description_lines[0..first_n].join("\n"))
      @description_remain = to_html(description_lines[first_n + 1..line_num].join("\n"))
    elsif line_num > 1
      @description_first = to_html(description_lines[0..first_n].join("\n"))
      @description_remain = ''
    else
      @description_first = ''
      @description_remain = ''
    end
  end
```

I am a Ruby starter and encounter this rubocup warning: `Method has too many lines. [13/10]`

The following is whole code url:
https://github.com/RubyStarts3/YPBT-app/blob/master/views_objects/video_info_view.rb

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

```
def split_description(description, first_n)
  @description_first, @description_remain =
  case description.count("\n")
  when 0..first_n
    [description, '']
  else
    partition_description(description, first_n)
  end.map(&:to_html)
end

def partition_description(description, first_n)
  return ['', description] if first_n.zero?
  offset = 0
  description.each_line.with_index(1) do |s,i|
    offset += s.size
    return [description[0,offset], description[offset..-1]] if i == first_n
  end
end
```

I've assumed `to_html('') #=> ''`, but if that's not the case the modification is straightforward.

**Example**

So that we can see the effect of `to_html`, let's define it thusly.

```
def to_html(description)
  description.upcase
end

description =<<_
It was the best of times
it was the worst of times
it was the age of wisdom
it was the age of fools
_
```

```
split_description(description, 0)
@description_first
  #=> "" 
@description_remain
  #=> "IT WAS THE BEST OF TIMES\n..WORST OF TIMES\n..AGE OF WISDOM\n..AGE OF FOOLS\n" 

split_description(description, 1)
@description_first
  #=> "IT WAS THE BEST OF TIMES\n" 
@description_remain
  #=> "IT WAS THE WORST OF TIMES\n..AGE OF WISDOM\n..AGE OF FOOLS\n" 

split_description(description, 2)
@description_first
  #=> "IT WAS THE BEST OF TIMES\nIT WAS THE WORST OF TIMES\n" 
@description_remain
  #=> "IT WAS THE AGE OF WISDOM\nIT WAS THE AGE OF FOOLS\n" 

split_description(description, 3)
@description_first
  #=> "IT WAS THE BEST OF TIMES\n..WORST OF TIMES\n..AGE OF WISDOM\n" 
@description_remain
  #=> "IT WAS THE AGE OF FOOLS\n" 

split_description(description, 4)
@description_first
  #=> "IT WAS THE BEST OF TIMES\n..WORST OF TIMES\n..AGE OF WISDOM\n..AGE OF FOOLS\n" 
@description_remain
  #=> ""
```

**Explanation**

Firstly, is appears that `description` is a local variable holding a string. If so, it must be an argument of the method (along with `first_n`).

```
def split_description(description, first_n)
```

We want to assign values to two instance variables, so let's begin by writing

```
  @description_first, @description_remain =
```

There are really two steps: obtaining the desired strings and then mapping them with `to_html`. So let's first concentrate on the first step.

We will now condition on the number of lines in the string

```
  case description.count("\n")
```

First, let's deal with the case where the string contains no newlines

```
  when 0
    [description, '']
```

If the string is empty this will be `['', '']`; otherwise it will contain a single string without a newline.

Next, suppose the number of newlines in the string is between 1 and `first_n`. In this case `@description_first` is to be the entire string and `@description_remain` is to be empty.

```
  when 1..first_n
      [description, '']
```

As both `when 0` and `when 1..first_n` return the same two-element array, we can combine them:

```
  when 0..first_n
    [description, '']
```

To get this far, `first_n` is less than the number of newlines. I've used another method for the case where the number of newlines is greater than `first_n`.

```
  else
    partition_description(description, first_n)
```

`partition_description` simply determines the offset into `description` of the `first_n`th newline, and then partitions the string accordingly.

Lastly, we need to end the case statement, map the array of two strings returned with `to_html` and end the method

```
  end.map(&:to_html)
end
```

As I mentioned earlier, I've assumed `to_html('') #=> ''`. That seems to me to be the best place do deal with empty strings.

Note that I've dealt with the string directly, rather than splitting the string into lines, manipulating the lines and then rejoining them.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's used or blanked in every condition, initialize the instance  variables to blank.

```
  def split_description(first_n)
    description_lines = description.split "\n"
    line_num = description_lines.length

    @description_first = ''
    @description_remain = ''

    if line_num > first_n
      @description_first = to_html(description_lines[0..first_n].join("\n"))
      @description_remain = to_html(description_lines[first_n + 1..line_num].join("\n"))
    elsif line_num > 1
      @description_first = to_html(description_lines[0..first_n].join("\n"))
    end
  end
```

I'd also move the logic for `description_lines[first_n + 1..line_num].join("\n")` to a method like `to_html( whatever_that_is( lines, from, to) )` or the like. Then it's not so bad if you repeat the same call and the name will describe what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

If `first_n` is always greater than 1 I think you can modify a little the Schwern's answer:

```
...

@description_first = to_html(description_lines[0..first_n].join("\n")) if line_num > 1

  if line_num > first_n
        @description_remain = to_html(description_lines[first_n + 1..line_num].join("\n"))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
def split_description(description, first_n = 0)
  lines = description.each_line
  @description_first  = to_html(lines.take(first_n).join)
  @description_remain = to_html(lines.drop(first_n).join)
end
```

[`take`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) and [`drop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop) replace all your logic, because, as @Cary Swoveland mentionned in a comment :

- if you take too much, you end up with the complete array, without error message
- if you drop too much, you end ud with an empty array, without error message

Example :

```
[1,2].take(99) #=> [1, 2]
[1,2].drop(99) #=> []
```

Also `each_line` outputs an Array of Strings, with newlines still present. No `split`, `chomp` or `join("\n")` is needed.

Comment: Indeed it does! Nice one, Eric. When used with the example in my answer we get the same results.  You are making use of the fact that [`1,2].take(99) #=> [1, 2]` and  `[1,2].drop(99) #=> []`, which may make it a challenge for the  reader to understand what's going on. I'm not suggesting you change that, but perhaps add one or two comments to clarify. What am I saying? A comment in a method posted to SO?